# Philip III of France in Latin

Tags: history, word-choice, french

Philip III of France is called "the Bold" ("le Hardi" in French).
The Latin Wikipedia page translates: "Philippus Animosus" but I can't find any historical source using this name.

Is there an historically attested version of "the Bold" where referring to kings, and especially Philip III? If not, is *animosus* a proper translation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[*Animosus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Danimosus2) (courageous, spirited, undaunted) is certainly not totally off-base and can be a fine translation for “bold.” For “le hardi” it seems a bit vague; more specific would be [*audax*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Daudax) (daring, audacious; but also rash, foolhardy).

And indeed there is no Google Books hit for “Philippus Animosus,” it appears to be a complete invention by Vicipaedia. On the other hand, you will find numerous instances of “Philippus Audax.” Many of these seem to refer to a different “Philipp the Bold,” i.e. Philipp II, Duke of Burgundy (whom even Vicipaedia [calls](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philippus_Audax) *Philippus Audax*), but others do refer to Philipp III of France, such as [this one](https://www.google.de/books/edition/Recueil_des_historiens_des_Gaules_et_de/4Yva3jlEf7cC?hl=de&gbpv=1&pg=PA540&printsec=frontcover), which incidentally also describes him as *animosus* in the text.

Thus it seems fair to conclude that the proper and common Latinization for “Philipp the Bold” is *Philippus Audax*.